# Locally download and prepare microdata

Tags: r, database, function, statistics, package

I ask for help regarding the use of the function to work with data from the PNS (National Health Survey)

Help me understand a initial result... such as:

```
" # people with self evaluated health good or very good  
      x$saude_b_mb <- as.numeric( x$n001 %in% c( '1' , '2' ) )"
```

I was able to install the lodown  package and the function that you provide in:

https://rdrr.io/github/ajdamico/lodown/src/R/pns.R#sym-get_catalog_pns

I think that my problem is specifically in output_dir.

[image]

Comment: This isn't really a question. You need to state your situation (preferably with example data), what you did and what happened afterwards (preferably with code), and what you expected to happen and why had happened didn't meet your expectations. I don't think you've really done any of those.

Comment: http://asdfree.com/pesquisa-nacional-de-saude-pns.html

Comment: Where does the function store the results? I got this message when running the function, and I'm not sure if it is working as intended...

p.s. I did all the steps you described.

Comment: Not 100% sure of your exact process here. But I see in output_dir="C:" This looks like a road to nowhere. maybe it should be output_dir="G:/"  or specify an output dir as output_dir="G:/your_folder_here" remember in R when specify a directory need to have / slash versus traditional back slash \

Comment: @AndrewBannerman thank you. 

I specified the directory and the same message still appears.


> get_catalog_pns(data_name = "pns" , output_dir="C:\\PNS")
  year full_url 2013 ftp://ftp.ibge.gov.br/PNS/2013/microdados/pns_2013_microdados_2017_03_23.zip
 output_folder long_file all_file

C:\\PNS/ 2013 long questionnaire survey.rds 2013 all questionnaire survey.rds long_design                               all_design
2013 long questionnaire survey design.rds 2013 all questionnaire survey design.rds

Comment: Can you perhaps edit the question with your steps, inputs / desired outputs etc.. it would be easier to help with clearer and more information!

Comment: hi `get_catalog_pns` is not exported from `library(lodown)` so not intended for users..  the PNS code on asdfree.com walks through each step to get started with this dataset, thanks

Comment: Ok. Thanks! 
I'll try!